# Calculate Business Hours between two columns in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Relatively new Python user so I apologize if this is a simple solution that I'm overlooking.

I'm trying to calculate the duration in business hours between two columns in Pandas.  I found this code that works when a specific date is applied to the startdate and enddate, but I do not know how to substitute my column data for the startdate/enddate.  When I substitute the df data, I get the error below.

Test Data:

print(df)

```
           ReqRecv             CompRecv
```

0  2022-07-01 15:03:25 2022-07-01 11:16:38
1  2022-07-01 14:24:15 2022-07-01 11:16:56
2  2022-07-01 14:10:44 2022-07-01 11:17:27
3  2022-06-29 13:09:54 2022-06-29 13:07:40

Code:

```
from business_duration import businessDuration
import pandas as pd
from datetime import time,datetime
import holidays as pyholidays

startdate=df['ReqRecv']
enddate=df['CompRecv']
starttime=time(9,0,0)
endtime=time(17,0,0)
holidaylist = pyholidays.US()holidaylist = pyholidays.US()
unit='hour'

print(businessDuration(startdate,enddate,starttime,endtime,holidaylist=holidaylist,unit=unit))

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I've been looking all over trying to find a solution and haven't had any luck as yet.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. You hand a list of start dates and end dates to the method, but it expects single dates. You need to hand it to the method one by one. You can use `apply()` with `axis=1` to call that method row-wise for the whole DataFrame and save the returns to an output column.
2. The method expects dates in the `DateTime` format, so you need to convert them before handing the dates to the method, e.g. by using `pd.to_datetime()`.
3. Your enddates are earlier than your startdates, so the method would by default still return `np.NaN` even with the other two issues fixed. The method only returns a valid results if the enddates are after the start dates.

Fix these three issues and it works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ReqRecv": ["2022-07-01 13:03:25", "2022-07-01 10:24:15"],
                   "CompRecv": ["2022-07-01 14:24:15", "2022-07-01 11:16:56"]})

starttime = time(9, 0, 0)
endtime = time(17, 0, 0)
holidaylist = pyholidays.US()
unit = 'hour'

df["diff_in_business_duration"] = df.apply(
    lambda row: businessDuration(pd.to_datetime(row["ReqRecv"]), pd.to_datetime(row["CompRecv"]), 
    starttime, endtime, holidaylist=holidaylist, unit=unit), axis=1)

print(df)
>                ReqRecv             CompRecv  diff_in_business_duration
  0  2022-07-01 13:03:25  2022-07-01 14:24:15                   1.347222
  1  2022-07-01 10:24:15  2022-07-01 11:16:56                   0.878056
```